# Get the last logon timestamp for multiple users

Tags: function, loops, powershell, memory, active-directory

The following code queries all the controllers in my environment to make sure i am getting the latest login timestamp.  It works great for getting data for the odd user I work on.  However, I am finding a need to evaluate 800+ users in AD.
 This eats 1.5gb before it finishes and crashes the script with out of memory errors.  Is there some way to reclaim the memory after the function finishes, or a way to force garbage collection?  I have tried remove-variable and other variants.  I have tried forcing occasional system garbage collection to no avail.

My guess is all the AD queries, just do not know how to deal with them once I am done.

The calls to this function are from inside a foreach loop that is sending each user from a list that I pulled prior to the function calls.  Thanks in advance for any help I can get.

The $domain variable, just pretend it is "example.contoso.ca"

```
    function getDateTimeStamp
{
  param
  (
    [string]$userID,

    [string]$domain,

    [string]$attribute #this is an AD attribute in this case i used "lastlogon"
  )
$domainSuffix = '*.'+$domain 
    $myForest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest() 
    $domaincontrollers = $myForest.Sites | % { $_.Servers } | Select-Object Name | Where-Object Name -like $domainSuffix
    $realUserDate = $null
    foreach ($domainController in $domainControllers)  
    { 
        $userDateTime = Get-ADUser -Identity $userID -Properties $attribute -Server $domainController.Name
        $userLastDateTime = $userDateTime.$attribute
        if($userLastDateTime -eq $null){$userLastDateTime = 0}
        elseif($userLastDateTime -eq 9223372036854775807){$userLastDateTime = 0}
        if($userLastDateTime -is 'DateTime'){$tempUserDate = get-date -Date ($userLastDateTime)}
        else{$tempUserDate = [DateTime]::FromFileTime([Int64]::Parse($userLastDateTime))}
        if ($realUserDate -le $tempUserDate){$realUserDate = $tempUserDate}
    }
    return $realUserDate
}
```

Comment: See my answer here, but try Foreach-Object 
http://superuser.com/questions/675484/why-does-foreach-object-behave-differently-when-called-as-foreach

Comment: i tried foreach ($x in $items)
and i tried $items | foreach-object{}
neither worked all the way through the list.

Comment: I don't see where you ever define `$attribute`. If you use LastLogonDate for `$attribute` you don't have to convert `[Int64]` to `[DateTime]`. Also, do you need the exact LastLogon, or can you use LastLogonTimestamp? That is replicated, and is accurate to within 11 days I believe.

Comment: So you didn't read the link at all

Comment: i added more info on attribute, i will look into that and report back. @austin i did read it, perhaps i misunderstood. my reply to you was me trying to indicate i tried the foreach cmdlet and statement mentioned.

Comment: `$attribute` must be lastLogon if there's any point in executing like this. LastLogonDate is the parsed version of lastLogonTimeStamp in the MS AD Cmdlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick post, in a bit of a hurry. This is an example of how you might make your function process a pipeline. If it works on a pipeline it needs (barely) any memory assigned.

```
function Get-ADDateTime
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('SamAccountName')]
        [string]$userID,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$domain,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$attribute
    )

    begin {
        $domainSuffix = '*.'+$domain 
        $myForest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest() 
        $domaincontrollers = $myForest.Sites.Servers | Where-Object Name -like $domainSuffix
    }

    process {
        # Pick an epoch, any epoch
        $date = Get-Date '01/01/1601'
        foreach ($domainController in $domainControllers)
        { 
            $adUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $userID -Properties $attribute -Server $domainController.Name
            if ($adUser.$attribute -notin $null, 9223372036854775807, 0) {
                if ($adUser.$attribute -is [DateTime]) {
                    $thisDate = $adUser.$attribute
                } else {
                    $thisDate = [DateTime]::FromFileTime([Int64]::Parse($adUser.$attribute))
                }

                if ($thisDate -gt $date) {
                    $date = $thisDate
                }
            }
        }
        if ($date -eq (Get-Date '01/01/1601')) { $date = $null }

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            UserID    = $UserID
            LastLogon = $date
        }
    }
}

Get-ADUser | Get-ADDateTime -Attribute $lastLogon -Domain 'domain'
```